# JDeveloper - how to generate stub class

Tags: java, jdeveloper, stub

I'm new in Java and JDeveloper.
I have to maintain two applications- first is for the public part of a website, second is for administrative part of a website. 
Both projects use same database. I have added in a table contacts two new fields. In JDeveloper successfully I did updating model project in first application public part - entity and view - added attributes from a database, also edited necessary java classes for the attributes. 
But in the second application for administration I have problem. Second application uses model classes from first application. When I update from the database, JDeveloper shows me file with .class extension, which has following heading:
This is Oracle stub generated class
I need to regenerate that class again in order to show and then use two new attributes.
I do not know what are the steps in JDeveloper - my version is 1.1.1.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an ADF Library that contains the model project from your first application.
Then you add this jar file to your second applicaiton - and you'll be able to use the updated ADF BC.
Read more about ADF Libraries here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/web.1112/e16182/reusing_components.htm#BEIGHHCG